# Is it possible to downgrade firmware via ADB sideload?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, downgrade, side-loading, asus-zenfone-5

I have an Asus zenfone 2. I want to downgrade it from firmware 2.19 to 2.18. They both are built on Android 5.0

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @firelord I have done many changes in my phone after rooting and  xposed framework. I'm facing some issues. So i want to do a clean rom installation. Since latest firmware zip is not yet available on Asus website, so i was thinking if can sideload previous firmware and then take the OTA

Comment: You can theoretically do it as long as you can boot into Recovery mode, and have the correct zip. **Take Backup before proceeding**. But because the device is rooted, I assume a custom Recovery would be installed (do it if there isn't any), then why not use the standard way of flashing using Recovery's GUI rather than going for ADB sideload?